# Angular unit test re-run on change; insert shell command?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

Sorry, not sure how to word or search for this. You know how when you have your unit tests running in a console window and they re-run whenever you make and save changes? I'd like to insert a call to a shell command before it runs. The command I want to run is a command I have to clear the console window. I'm needing to stop and restart the test because I can't easy tell where one bunch of errors starts and another starts.

(I'm working on a macbook.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting, although I have never needed this, I think you can use the `karma-clear-screen-reporter` plugin and configure the plugin.

https://github.com/arthurc/karma-clear-screen-reporter

Comment: Yep, it does seem to work. I'm on Angular 4.3 and will try it on a Ang. 9 project later.